My 2D ArrayList syntax is not working in Netbeans
I am following BroCode's Java Full Course on YouTube and encountered this error. NetBeans IDE does not allow the syntax ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> groceryList = new ArrayList<String>(); when in BroCode's video, it worked fine.
He was using Eclipse IDE while I use NetBeans. Does the difference of IDEs affect the syntax?
Here is the screenshot of my code:


First of all, read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? Then check carefully how the list declaration in the 1st code differs from your declaration. Then think carefully why ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> is different from ArrayList<String>.

Also take the [tour] and read [ask].

In my (limited) experience, YouTube videos that [endeavor to] teach Java are very poor quality. If you want to learn Java and are willing to try a resource that is not a video, then I recommend Oracle Java Tutorials.

The type of the variable must match the type of the object that you created; or be a supertype of it.
You can also use the diamond operator, which means you omit everything inside the <> characters after new.
It's not clear from your description exactly what you're trying to do, but the following should all work.  Most likely, the one you want is the fifth one.
// If you really want a list of lists of strings
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> groceryList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();  

// The same thing using the diamond operator to save typing
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> groceryList = new ArrayList<>();  


// If all you want is a list of strings, you could use this
ArrayList<String> groceryList = new ArrayList<String>();  

// Or you could use the diamond operator for this too.
ArrayList<String> groceryList = new ArrayList<>();  

// But once the list is created, nothing in your code should really care 
// whether it's an ArrayList, or some other kind of List, so it makes a
// lot of sense to store it in a List variable, like this.
List<String> groceryList = new ArrayList<>();  

